# MySQL indexing with functions

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-5.6, sql-optimization

We have a use-case where we need to copy a large table (with some heavy DML activity - 10K/sec) in near real time. The following is the table structure (MySQL 5.6) -

```
  id bigint(20) -> Auto-increment PK field,
  error_text (longtext),
  production_id int(11),
  timestamp bigint(20),
  edited_timestamp bigint(20)
```

We are using the following polling query -

```
  select * from table where timestamp > ? order by timestamp ASC limit 50000 (Index on timestamp column)
```

Soon, we started observing copy lag (considering network latency and query execution overhead) and now we want to run more polling instances in parallel. We tried to split the queries by using a MOD based query - MOD(production_id, N).

```
  select * from table where MOD(production_id, 2) = 0 AND timestamp > ? order by timestamp ASC limit 50000;
 select * from table where MOD(production_id, 2) != 0 AND timestamp > ? order by timestamp ASC limit 50000;
```

However, this wasn't working as MySQL 5.6 doesn't support function based indices and there's too much overlap between queries - as optimizer was using the timestamp index and then filtering out the result-set. One possible solution is to create a MOD based column and then add an index on it (MOD column + timestamp).

Since, our table is so large migration (adding new column and index) can take a long time. So, we are wondering if there are any alternative options that we can consider. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216108/discussion-on-question-by-v1666-mysql-indexing-with-functions).